# Word count bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this program that I want to tell the user how may time a user inputted word appears in a file. This is what i have written so far but it doesn't work.

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "Enter the file that is to be searched (~/test/new)"
        read location
echo "Enter the search term"
        read search
$result = (grep -w "$search" $location | wc -w)
echo "The search term" $search "appears "$result" time/s in "$location
```

What could I do to make it work?

Comment: In what ways doesn't your script work? Error messages would certainly hint at what is wrong.

Comment: Your command substitution / assignment is messed up in at least 3 ways: try `result=$( ... )` to start

Answer (score 1):

The core command that you want should, if I understand correctly,
count each occurrence of the word searched for. Assuming GNU grep:

```
<"$file" grep -Fwo -- "$word" | wc -l
```

Option `-F` switches to non-regexp, verbatim string matching. `-w`
does a word search, as in you question, and `-o` prints each match
alone, on its own line, resulting in the proper count being emitted by
`wc -l`.

Now, about prompting, you could take advantage of the fact that bash
`read` has a `-p` option:

```
read -p 'Filename: ' file
read -p 'Word: ' word
```

Assignment takes the form `var=value`, with no dollar sign or
spaces around the equal sign:

```
count=$(grep-command)
```

Finally, you can take advantage of string interpolation when writing
your output:

```
echo "File '$file' contains this many occurrences of '$word': $count."
```

Comment: I edited the file as suggested and i now get the error:

    File Location: ~/Test/test

    Word: Hello

    ./wordFinder.bash: line 10: ~/Test/test: No such file or directory

    The search term 'Hello' appears '0' time/s in '~/Test/test'

Comment: That's because tilde expansion doesn't happen. You could require the user to type a complete path (not using the `~` character), or have a look at this question for other options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

Taking a wild guess here, as I did not try anything.

Tilde expansion is a bit cumbersome in variables, as it is expanded before variables arte expanded.

Does it work OK with file names without a tilde?

Also, you would do good to test some assumptions, like `$location` being a readable file. You might want to exit with a helpful message. This possibly will also help you debug your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -sc "\n$input" '[\n*]' <in | grep -xcFe"$input"
```

...would probably do it pretty efficiently. But it will probably not work especially well if you mean to only match *whole* words. For that you can do:

```
tr \[:space:]\[:punct:] '[\n*]' <in | grep -xcFe"$input"
```

...or perhaps...

```
tr -c \[:alnum:]_ '[\n*]' <in | grep -xcFe"$input"
```

...whichever you feel is most appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I updated what you were attempting to do with some basic debugging, while achieving what I believe you desire:

```
read -p "Please specify a location/file to be searched...Example=/var/tmp/test.txt     : " location
while [[ ! -f ${location} ]] ; do
  read -p "Unable to located file specified, please try again" location
done
read -p "Please specify a search term :" search
result=$(grep -w ${search} ${location} | wc -w)
echo "The search term ${search}, appears ${result} times inside of ${location}"
```